# WordPress Theme Responsive Using @media Not Working

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress and I hope I am explaining my problem correctly.

I am using the Genesis Theme with a child theme and custom code. The child theme is responsive and my custom code consists of rules such as:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 240px;
}

.picture {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

To note, most of my page uses the custom code classes instead of the ones from the child theme. I have heard that I should try @media in the custom code to make it responsive. I tested it using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #content {
   max-width: 600px;
  width: 66.7%; 
 }
#sidebar {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 33.3%; 
 }
}
```

But it had no effect at all. Any comment would help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `@media query` method this way?

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
 and (min-device-width : 320px)
 and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```